# Weird popup menu in AlertDialog with custom background style

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

How can I get the popup menu which I see throughout the app otherwise (see below)? I tried experimenting with `popupMenuStyle`and `popupMenuBackground` but nothing changes.

[image]

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.style.AlertDialogStyle);
...
builder.show();
```

AlertDialogStyle:

```
    <style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogTitleStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<!--        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu</item>-->
<!--        <item name="popupMenuBackground">@color/red</item>-->
        <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonNeutralStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
```

If I comment `android:background`, Popup Menu is OK:

[image]

Comment: Please check your '<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>' change it to white color

Comment: @Sniffer, kindly check my update at the end of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Instead of using

```
<item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

in my custom style, I should've used

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

[image]